# Дизайн двух кнопок

Tags: html, css

Всем привет, посмотрел на одном сайте американском прикольную фишку и решил сделать подобное. Чтобы сделать как-бы одну кнопку, но одна синяя, а другая прозрачная но с цветом кнопки. Решил сделать немного костыльно, а именно две кнопки поставить на одну позицию, но столкнулся с проблемой. Как убрать конец кнопки, или как это будет все правильно реализовать

```css
.acbutton {
 position: relative;
 width: 140px;
 top: 150px;
 height: 40px;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 25px;
 font-family: 'Webnar';
 background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(41, 182, 246,1.0),rgba(66, 165, 245,1.0));
 color: white;
 outline: none;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.video {
  position: relative;
 width: 190px;
 top: 150px;
 right: 300px;
 height: 40px;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 25px;
 font-family: 'Webnar';
 background: rgba(1,1,1,0);
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(1,1,1,0.5);
 color: white;
 outline: none;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a href=""></a><button class="acbutton">Скачать античит</button>
   <a href=""><button class="video" style="color: rgba(41, 182, 246,1.0)">Посмотреть видео</button></a>
```

[image: Это как у меня]

Вот так должно быть

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код посмотреть бы

Comment: на нижней картинке у вас `input` и `submit`, но если даже вы хотели скопировать стили, то скорее всего нужно поставить `z-index` для второй кнопки

Comment: Я добавил код, можете подправить пожалуйста

Comment: Если все ок, отметьте мой ответ как решение

Answer (score 3):

Намудрили вы со стилями, конечно, особенно с позиционированием, трогать не буду, выполню только вашу проблему с наложением

```css
.acbutton {
 position: relative;
 width: 140px;
 top: 150px;
 height: 40px;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 25px;
 font-family: 'Webnar';
 background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(41, 182, 246,1.0),rgba(66, 165, 245,1.0));
 color: white;
 outline: none;
 cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 10;
}

.video {
  position: relative;
 width: 190px;
 top: 150px;
 right: 300px;
 height: 40px;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 25px;
 font-family: 'Webnar';
 background: rgba(1,1,1,0);
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(1,1,1,0.5);
 color: white;
 outline: none;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a href=""></a><button class="acbutton">Скачать античит</button>
   <a href=""><button class="video" style="color: rgba(41, 182, 246,1.0)">Посмотреть видео</button></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Размер картинки у примера очень маленький, но пытался сделать максимально похоже.

```css
.two-button {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
}

.two-button a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.two-button a:nth-child(1) {
  min-width: 250px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #757575;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.15), 0 0 15px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}

.two-button a:nth-child(2) {
  background: #4a90e1;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1) inset;
  margin-left: -32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="two-button">
  <a href="#">Смотреть видео</a>
  <a href="#">Скачать античит</a>
</div>
```